# Find if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos n\sin\frac{1}{n}}{n}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

As far as I understand this is a Leibniz series therefore it's converging. What I was thinking is finding a way to "change" the $\cos n$ to $\cos {\pi n}=(-1)^n$ and get a $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n}}{n}$$

I'm new to this subject so I don't know how to formally do it (if it's even possible and i'm in the right direction).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using $\;\sin\frac1n\le\frac1n\;$ , you get:

$$\left|\frac{\cos n\sin\frac1n}{n}\right|\le\frac1{n^2}$$

annd the comparison test gives you absolute convoergence ( of course, we also used $\;|\cos n|\le1\;$).

Comment: OK I understand your solution. Out of curiosity, is there a way to do it using the fact that the sequence is switching signs and converges to zero?

Comment: @PanthersFan92 The sequence switches signs but it isn't alternating. You can also try Dirichlet's test or even (perhaps better) Abel's test (google this)

Comment: What do you mean by "alternating"?

Comment: @PanthersFan92  the signs alternate: plus,  minus, plus...etc.